# How can I make a script that holds a key down using Python? (for a game)

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script that would hold the W key down (for a game, so the character would move forward automatically) and the Left Button on the mouse down (also for the game) until a certain key was pressed that would stop the loop.

In using Spyder and Anaconda as my package manager.
I have tried using pynput and pyautogui as seen bellow:

```
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.keyDown("w")
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.keyUp("w")
```

so that the w key would be held for 5 seconds and type output something like:
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

I have tried a similar script with pyinput but without any success as the w key only gets outputted once:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press('w')
time.sleep(5)
keyboard.release('e')
```

So the issue is that the script doesn't hold down w, just presses it once
Is there a simple way to make this using python? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import time, pyautogui
def hold_w (hold_time):
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < hold_time:
        pyautogui.press('w')
```

Also you can do multiple presses using

```
pyautogui.press('w', presses=10)
```

or you can modify the `while` logic above to escape on a different key press.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help but what I need is a continuous press, like when you hold a key down to move a player in a game or when you hold the left mouse button down. The script outputs several non-continuous clicks. Is there any way of getting that continuous output of when you psychically hold won a key on your keyboard for a given amount of time ?